# How i can change the language to radio for Mazda Axela 2014?

Tags: mazda, audio, mazda-3

how can i change the language to radio  for Mazda Axela 2014
what type of video can play the dvd?

Comment: Thanks for the question, and welcome to the site. It would be helpful to know what you've already tried or where you got stuck.

Comment: To get headed in the right direction, click the Home icon, and then the Gear to get to settings (page 299 in linked pdf). Haven't found complete instructions, but this should help get you closer. https://www.mymazda.com/MusaWeb/pdf/manuals/2014_MAZDA3_OM.pdf